# Correct build.gradle for XE17

Tags: google-glass

After Glass updated to XE17 and I made updates in Android SDK manager, I can no longer compile the project. This is my config:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 5
        versionName "5.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
}
```

but Glass related packages like

```
import com.google.android.glass.app.Card;
import com.google.android.glass.media.CameraManager;
```

are not avaiable.
Here's status of my SDK Manager:

[image: SDK Manager]

What should I change in order to be able to compile the project in Android Studio again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion "Google Inc.:Glass Development Kit Preview:19"
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hi, where do I set this?

Comment: In your `<APP_ROOT>/app/build.gradle` file.